# Bluetooth LE on Raspbian

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspbian, bluez

I installed bluez-5.15 from source with the following configuration:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --sysconfdir=/etc \
--localstatedir=/var --libexecdir=/lib --disable-systemd
```

Then I had to copy gatttool manually into the /usr/local/bin dir

```
$ sudo cp attrib/gatttool /usr/local/bin/
```

I rebooted the Raspberry Pi and tried the following to connect to my BLE device:

```
$ sudo hciconfig hci0 up

$ sudo hcitool lescan
LE Scan ...  
EA:FB:B5:CE:B0:13 DfuTarg

$ sudo hcitool lewladd EA:FB:B5:CE:B0:13

$ sudo hcitool lecc EA:FB:B5:CE:B0:13
Could not create connection: Input/output error
```

So then I tried to connect with gatttool:

```
$ gatttool -b EA:FB:B5:CE:B0:13 --interactive
[EA:FB:B5:CE:B0:13][LE]> connect
Attempting to connect to EA:FB:B5:CE:B0:13
Error: connect error: Device or resource busy (16)
[EA:FB:B5:CE:B0:13][LE]>
```

What am I missing here - is this a configuration issue? What do the errors mean?

Comment: Is this a USB dongle?  If you try unplugging it and re-plugging it in does that fix it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First off, I spoke with a colleague about my configuration and for Raspbian (or more specifically, Debian) he recommended the following configuration settings:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --enable-library --with-systemdsystemunitdir=/lib/systemd/system --with-systemduserunitdir=/usr/lib/systemd
```

Afterward, upon further inspection, here is how I was able to successfully connect. So what was happening was that the device I was trying to connect to (an NRF-based BLE device) required the LE address flag to be set to 'random'. See below:

```
gatttool -t random -b EA:FB:B5:CE:B0:13 -I
```

Then the result:

```
[EA:FB:B5:CE:B0:13][LE]> connect
Attempting to connect to EA:FB:B5:CE:B0:13
Connection successful
[EA:FB:B5:CE:B0:13][LE]> characteristics
handle: 0x0002, char properties: 0x0a, char value handle: 0x0003, uuid: 00002a00
-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

Huzzah! Also, there may be a need to set the security level to something lower than high:

```
[EA:FB:B5:CE:B0:13][LE]> sec-level medium
```

Comment: I keep getting an error when I try to use the `-t` parameter: `Unknown option -t`. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Check the version of bluez. I was using 5.15 for Debian.

Comment: nevermind, I re-installed bluez with the latest version and it now runs great. Thanks anyway!

Comment: had the same problem, I guess the -t random was the key

Answer (score 5):

From my experience with Bluez 5.15

1. Ensure you have no connections to the BLE device (check with *hcitool con*).
2. Do *not* run *hcitool lecc*.
3. Start *gatttool* like in your question.
4. In *gatttool* run *connect* command. If the command hangs, then press button on the device (i.e. sometimes needed when connecting to SensorTag).

I believe earlier versions of Bluez required *hcitool lecc* step, but it is not the case anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, but I believe I resolved the connection issue. I was finally able to connect using the random address flag in gatttool. Also, my device did not have a button (I am not suing the SensorTag).