# Bluetooth LE on Raspbian does not bond with nRF

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have an Rpi3 and I want to bond it with nRF which is connected to my laptop via UART. This nRF-laptop connection shows me whether Rpi3 is connected and/or paired with nRF. I am able to connect to the nRF device by running:

```
    gatttool -t random -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -I
```

I [found](https://clarkli86.wordpress.com/2015/02/15/test-bluetooth-le-pairing-bluez/) that to be able to pair it, all I need to do is run the following command after I connected using gattool:

```
    sec-level medium
```

However, nRF device only showed "Connected".

Then I tried using *bluetoothctl* command. I made sure the power is on, agent is on, it's discoverable and etc. After I ran the command *pair XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX*, it said it was successful. This was also confirmed after running *info XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX*. Yet nRF device did not react to the pairing. If I connect to nRF device through my phone using "nRF Connect" app, then nRF shows that my phone is paired.

I am running:

```
Linux 4.9.13-v7+ #974 SMP Wed Mar 1 20:09:48 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
Bluez-5.44
```

I followed tutorials from [adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/install-bluez-on-the-raspberry-pi/installation/) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22213793/bluetooth-le-on-raspbian/). I read that for Bluez-5.44 I do not need to run bluetooth in the experimental mode.

What am I missing? I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To any lost souls who might have also been stuck in this situation, here is how I solved it (you need to run sudo for the following commands):

```
$ service bluetooth stop

$ /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
```

If the nRF device has been paired once and then restarted, that means the pairing key is still on Pi's side which needs to be removed and can be done by:

```
$ bluetoothctl
$ remove XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
$ exit
```

After this you need to start bluetooth device:

```
$ hciconfig hci0 up
```